# How to locate an element with reference to an element in Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want achieve similar functionality of `webElement.findBy(By.xpath("xpath_locator"));`  in Page Object Model framework with `@FindBy` annotation.

For example:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "xpath_locator_1")

public WebElement wbel_1;
```

I want to find out next WebElement with reference to "wbel_1", how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more ? What do you mean by* next WebElement with reference to "wbel_1"  * ? You mean to say you want all web elements which are inside wbel_1 in the HTML DOM tree ? or Next element after this element on page ? Can you please share your HTML source code and expain a little more  what is your exact  requirement ?

Comment: Yes @rahulrai, I want to select a specific element inside wbel_1.
I want to achieve similar functionality as
webElement.findElement(By by);

Answer (score 0):

Xpath Axes are the solution.You can use the preceding and following functions of xpath for this.

> xpath_locator_1/following::tagname[n]

following selects everything in the document after the closing tag of the current node.

**Please check out this link:** 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Indeed this link is helpful, but it's not what I am looking for it.